# Regex not working for me

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a regular expression to find out the third delimiter "/" and if match found then grab entire sentence before it and delete rest.

```
black / white / green / blue / delta / orange / yellow / pink...(n)
```

outcome should be

```
black / white / green
```

I tried this `(.*(\/{2,3}))` but it did not work.

Comment: What does it mean *did not work*?

Comment: Hello I have made a correction on my outcome by removing the last node "/". Could you please help me out. I tried by my own but was unsuccessful.

Comment: I guess you want get that substring you wanted without trailing slash. Try `^([^\/]*(?:\/[^\/]*){2}).*`.

Comment: Sorry for the last response. Yes that did work like I needed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `(.*(\/{2,3}))` matches any chars (perhaps, other than a newline) and then 2 or 3 `/` symbols, capturing the whole match into Group 1, and the forward slashes into Group 2. It may find the match anywhere inside a larger string, but it just effectively matches from the start of the string up to the last 2 or 2 `/` symbols on a line.

You can use

```
^((?:[^\/]*\/){3}).*
```

And replace with the `$1` backreference.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aA0eU2/1)

Depending on the input and the regex engine, you might need a DOTALL modifier for the `.` to match newlines, too.

Note that you can use a simpler `^((?:[^\/]*\/){3})` for *matching* your substring.

Also, if you have access to raw programming code, you could just split the string with `/`, take the first 3 elements, and join them back with `/`.

Comment: Thank you very much Wiktor. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
^(( ?\w+ \/){3})
```

Explanation:

( ?\w+ /) - it's matching *white*/ (_ is space, just marking here), but since first word is at the beggining of the line, it does not contain a space before word itself, so '?' after first space, which means optional.
{3} means find this group *white*/ occuring 3 times (no less, no bigger)
And all this is enclosed with ^() to not match f.e. 3 occurrences in the middle of the line.

Comment: I did not expected such a quick answer. I would really appreciate if you could also explain your code. just the one written above.